# Android SurfaceView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, surfaceview

I have a fragment with a SurfaceView.
If I change fragment (from A to B and then from B to A) I don't have problem. The same if I come back to other activities.
While, if I push the power button and then I re-push the power button, the surface view is blocked. It is like as if the fragment should be reloaded or the onCreateView should be called.
Now, my code is the following:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(TAG,"resume");        

    camera = null;
    preview = null;
    previewHolder = null;

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "CameraActivity");

    try {
        wakeLock.acquire();
        camera = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a (back) Camera instance
        preview = (SurfaceView) getView().findViewById(R.id.preview);
        previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera non disponibile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Home.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(TAG,"pause");

    if(camera!=null){
        surfaceCallback.surfaceDestroyed(previewHolder);
        previewHolder.removeCallback(surfaceCallback);
        if (wakeLock.isHeld()) wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

I would that when I come back to my fragment from power button the surfaceview is refreshed and so the fragment can do its task.
Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**
After a lot of time I have solved the problem alone. Maybe, the method is not very "kind" but it works for me! 
In onpause method I check if the screen is turned off. If it is, I reload the fragment.

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    //myStopPreview();
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(TAG,"pause");
    if(camera!=null){
        flag=2;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        surfaceCallback.surfaceDestroyed(previewHolder);

        previewHolder.removeCallback(surfaceCallback);
        //preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preview = null;
        previewHolder = null;
        camera = null;
        if (wakeLock.isHeld()) wakeLock.release();
    }

    if(!((PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isScreenOn()){
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_tag_fragment");
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Surface may not be destroyed if you blank/unblank the screen with the power button.  You appear to be calling the surfaceDestroyed() callback manually in your onPause() -- let the system do that itself when necessary.  See also http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity .

Comment: I thank you for the link. It was very clarifying. Since I want that when the screen un-blanks the task of the activity starts from the beginning, I think that the first method is better. Do you agree with me?

Comment: You can see an example of approach #1 here: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I verify the code of this example in my code!